# Switching between original condition and SequentialAnimation

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt6

Not sure how to express my question. My snippet code is just to illustrate what I want to achieve in a much bigger code base. I have an "originalCondition" that changes the opacity of an image which is independent of the SequentialAnimation. What I want to achieve after the SequentialAnimation has completed changing the opacity for the Image that the "originalCondition" binds back to the opacity. *Not sure if bind is the appropriate way to describe it*

For some reason, this does not occur and I am not sure why or how to do it.

```
Item {
    id: root
    property bool activatedLetter: false

    Button {
       text: "Click me"
       onClicked: root.activatedLetter = true
     }
         
    Image {
        id: headerBackgroundImage
        visible: true
        opacity: originalCondition 
    }

    SequentialAnimation {
        running: root.activatedLetter

        onStopped: {
            if(root.activatedLetter) {
                headerBackgroundImage.visible = true
            }
            headerBackgroundImage.opacity = 1
            root.activatedLetter = false
        }

        PauseAnimation {
           duration: 750
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            target: headerBackgroundImage
            property: "opacity"
            from: 1
            to: 0
            duration: 1000
        }

        NumberAnimation {
            target: headerBackgroundImage
            property: "visible"
            from: 1
            to:0
            duration: 1000
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your onStopped, instead of this:

```
headerBackgroundImage.opacity = 1
```

try this:

```
headerBackgroundImage.opacity = Qt.binding(() => originalCondition);
```